# SAS: unique identifier for multiple columns with overlapping values

Tags: grouping, nodes, combinations, permutation, uniqueidentifier

Take the example code below containing person and their session:

```
data test;
    length pers session $5;
    input pers $ session $;
    datalines;
    a   1
    a   2
    a   7
    b   2
    b   3
    c   3
    d   4
    e   5
    h   2
    ;
run;
```

The first 6 records and last record should have the same unique identifier because Person A, B, and H are linked by Session 2, and Person B (who is linked to Person A) is linked to Person C by Session 3.

i.e. All 7 records have linkage through person and/or session. If you think of person as the 'parent' and session as the 'child' in node structure, all linked children and parents should be in the same UID. Any breaks should be separate UIDs.

Rows 7 and 8 (Person D and E) would have their own unique identifiers because they have no overlapping persons or sessions. The result would look something like this:

```
Person|Session|Unique_ID
    a       1       UID1
    a       2       UID1
    a       7       UID1
    b       2       UID1
    b       3       UID1
    c       3       UID1
    h       2       UID1
    d       4       UID2
    e       5       UID3
```

I have tried transposing and multiple retains but it gets tricky going row by row as it seems like you have to retain partial matches but then go back up the groupings if there are full matches. I could be overthinking it but it seems quite complex.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I might achieve this?

Comment: How many rows will be in the data set ? What is most case anticipated? (the  synthetic group having the most number of customer+device combinations)

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/SAS-macro-for-finding-all-paths-in-a-directed-graph-network/ta-p/221568

Comment: If you have SAS OR, PROC BOM is also a good choice.

Comment: There are potentially thousands of rows and can be thought of as grouping family members or individuals with access to the same devices like computers or smartphones (i.e. there are 3 customers in a household who are using a total of 4 devices). There will never be something like 20 customers using 100 devices.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to PROC BOM -- that does look like a good choice for this.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified code again and it should work for this scenarios mentioned

```
proc sql;
create table test1 as 
select x.*, flag from 
(select * from test) x
 left join 
 (select distinct a.cust, case when a.dev = b.dev
 and a.cust ne b.cust then 1  end as flag from test a
 inner join
 test b
 on a.dev = b.dev
 and a.cust ne b.cust) y
 on x.cust = y.cust;



proc sort data =test1;
 by cust ;
 run;

  data test2;
  set test1;
   by cust;
   retain _flag;

   if flag = 1 then _flag = flag;
   else if  first.cust then  _flag +1;
  Unique_ID = cats("UID",_flag);
drop flag _flag ;
 run;
```

Comment: This worked for the original example but not in the actual data so I probably should have added more variations. Take the example data again above where there is now a Customer A and Device 7. This assigns UID1 correctly but then reassigns the UID for Customer B and C incorrectly.

Comment: I have modified code now device could be anywhere, if device is there then unique id will not increase

Comment: It is close but still does not work exactly. If you add a row to the example data for Customer H Device 2 (which should link to UID1 because of Device 2), it ends up getting its own UID3.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: what i mean is if any matching device  is there for any customer. All of those customers are grouped as 1 and get UID1. Else what you do is add +1 for every new customer and then get UID2 , UID3 etc.

Comment: That sounds correct. Thank you for your work on this by the way, it's getting over my head.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184824/discussion-between-kiran-and-foxer).

Comment: I marked it as correct but it still does not work. Again, it's close. But adding examples to the test data creates inaccuracies.

Comment: what is the issue you are having.

Comment: In the example data, if you add rows Customer I Device 9 and Customer Z Device 9 (which link to themselves but not any other records), they end up getting UID1 which is wrong.